# OWIN external login refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I'm using owin for my app, **Web Api2** for working with data and **MVC5** for view.

```
     static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";

        UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<User, int>(new UserRepository());
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(59),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        };

    }
```

When user is logged in through **/Token?username=x&password=x&grant_type=password**, it generates bearer token with refresh GUID for future refresh token **/Token?grant_type=refresh_token**, all is working okey.

My app can login through **Facebook**, etc, it's getting data I need from **Facebook (email, etc)** then I want to generate token with **refresh GUID**, problem is that for refreshing I need to pass data through /Token?username&password but my user doesn't have password, I tough to send additional parameter Scope and show what **provider and provider key** its using and to search in DB this user is registered and give him permission to generate token.

Is this good idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, without using garnt_type=password:

This is my refresh token class that AuthroizationServer is using

```
     public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();

        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {.......}
        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {.......}
    }
```

My AccountController is initialized like this:

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(Startup.UserManagerFactory(), Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat)
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<User, int> userManager, ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
        UserManager.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<User>(UserManager);
    }
```

Now I need to create AuthenticationTokenCreateContext and send it to my RefreshTokenProvider so it will add Refresh Guid in _refreshTokens, so when I will send my refreshGuid it will be valid. Where I'm creating Identity for ExternalUser

```
        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.Id.ToString());
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("TokenGuid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        await Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(Request.GetOwinContext(), AccessTokenFormat, ticket));
        Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity);
```

Now all my tokens can be refreshed, because I passed TokenGuid to RefreshTokenProvider, after that I'm creating token with that GUID and next time I will refresh it /Token?grant_type=refresh_token.....

P.S. If you need detailed help you can write me.

Comment: hi, I am doing the same stuff, but my problem is not setting the refreshTokenId in the response. Any Idea ? . Also why do need  Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity) ?

Comment: This last code is creating token with possibility to refresh in the future,   Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity); return response of token if I correctly remember it.

Answer (score 1):

A few extra remarks:

- If you're using the default accesstoken formats.

  - Remember to use for example: `Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenFormat`
    instead of `Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat`
  - Otherwise the decryptionstage will throw an exception
- To get the refresh token in de response of the getexternallogin you have to add a override in: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

```cs
public override Task AuthorizationEndpointResponse(OAuthAuthorizationEndpointResponseContext context)
{
            var refreshToken = context.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Properties.Dictionary["refresh_token"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
        }
        return base.AuthorizationEndpointResponse(context);
}
```